# DRF- Apply search on multiple table with no relation

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I would like to apply search on multiple fields those fields are split into two tables.
Tables does not have any foreign Key relation I have only one common field `transaction_id`.How can I achieve?

models.py,

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    emp_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default=None)
    emp_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    emp_status = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)


class EmployeeWorkFlowStatus(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default=None)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default=None)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

serializer.py,

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = "__all__"


class EmployeeWorkFlowStatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeWorkFlowStatus
        fields = "__all__"
```

How can I write views for search from both table and get from both tables? Will serializer will help in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get EmployeeWorkFlowStatus with Employee, you can update the  EmployeeSerializer like this,

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    employee_work_flow_status = serializer.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_employee_wark_flow_status(self, instance):
        return EmployeeWorkFlowStatusSerializer(EmployeeWorkFlowStatus.objects.get(transaction_id=instance.transaction_id)).data
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = "__all__"
```

employee_work_flow_status object will be added as a new field in the Serializer. Now you can search on the Employee table and get objects, you can do vice-versa as well and do the same in EmployeeWorkFlowStatusSerializer  .